# wordpress plugin to redirect defined url to another url option page showing permission error

Tags: php, wordpress

i was working on a plugin that can find some special url in wordpress page contents and then if matching URL found then change that url automatically to another url like without giving backlink benfit to that site.

for example :
if i have defined a site that start with www.site2.com           and i wants to redirect this to another site www.site3.com

now pluging will convert url found  www.site.com on page to   www.site.com/og.php=www.site2.com   now if user clicks this url this will be redirected to www.site3.com

after inslalling and activating plugin found urls are converting but when i clicks them getting error    "/og.php"  file not found

And when i have tried to open option page to add more url or changing some settings on page 
it's giving me error "you do not have permission to access this page"

below you can check my codes for both pages

**CODE FOR OPTION PAGE:**

```
<?php
/*
Author: Tasleem
Author URI: http://www.alitips.in
Description: Admin options for Automatic Affiliate Links on the fly
*/

$location = get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/st_auto_affiliate_links_options.php'; // Form Action URI


// Set a few defaults to get people started and use as examples
add_option('st_aal_before', 'http://www.hammacher.com
http://www.thinkgeek.com
http://www.blogrush.com');

add_option('st_aal_after', 'http://www.dpbolvw.net/j6117p-85-7NPVWPRURNPORVORWO?url=%ENCODED_TARGET%&cm_ven=CJ&cm_cat=1511450&cm_pla=1781363&cm_ite=Hammacher+Schlemmer&sid=%TARGET%
http://www.anrdoezrs.net/se121lnwtnvACIJCEHEACBEGHEDF?url=%ENCODED_TARGET%&sid=cg-%TARGET%
http://www.blogrush.com/r58661417');;

/*check form submission and update options*/
if ('process' == $_POST['stage'])
{
    update_option('st_aal_before', $_POST['st_aal_before']);
    update_option('st_aal_after', $_POST['st_aal_after']);
}

/* Get options for form fields */
$st_aal_before = get_option('st_aal_before');
$st_aal_after = get_option('st_aal_after');

?>


<div class="wrap"> 
  <h2><?php _e('Automatic Affiliate Links Options', 'st_ts_') ?></h2> 
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $location ?>&amp;updated=true">
    <input type="hidden" name="stage" value="process" />
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" class="editform">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%" valign="top"><strong>URLs that start with</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Replace with</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><textarea name="st_aal_before" id="st_aal_before" style="width: 95%;" rows="15" cols="50"><?php echo $st_aal_before; ?></textarea></td>
        <td valign="top"><textarea name="st_aal_after" id="st_aal_after" style="width: 95%;" rows="15" cols="50"><?php echo $st_aal_after; ?></textarea>
        <strong>Tokens:</strong><br>
        <i>%TARGET%</i> - original URL<br>
        <i>%ENCODED_TARGET%</i> - original URL encoded to be html friendly
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <p class="submit">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php _e('Update Options', 'st_ts_') ?> &raquo;" />
    </p>
      </form>
</div>
```

**code for programming page that will redirect url**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Automatic Affiliate Links
Plugin URI: http://www.alitips.in
Author: Tasleem
Author URI: http://www.alitips.in
Description: Changes Affiliate URLs to local URL which will then be forwarded by the local script
Date: September 18th, 2007
Version: 1.1
History:
18/09/2007  1.0.0   Initial Version
19/9/2007   1.0.01  Modifed (hacked) to cope with multiple ?s and &s in the initial URL

*/


$OutGoingURL =   "/og.php";

function ConvertURLs($aText)
{
    global $OutGoingURL;

    $st_aal_before = get_option('st_aal_before');
    $searchfor = explode("\r\n", trim($st_aal_before));

    for($i = 0; $i < count($searchfor); $i++)
    {
        $searchfor[$i] = "|href=['\"](" . $searchfor[$i] . ".*)/?['\"]|Ui";
    }

    get_option('siteurl');
    $aText = preg_replace($searchfor, "href='" . get_option('siteurl'). "$OutGoingURL?url=$1" ."'", $aText);    
    return $aText;
}


if(strstr( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $OutGoingURL))
{
    $st_aal_after = get_option('st_aal_after');
    $replacewith = explode("\r\n", trim($st_aal_after));

    $st_aal_before = get_option('st_aal_before');
    $searchfor = explode("\r\n", trim($st_aal_before));
    for($i = 0; $i < count($searchfor); $i++)
    {
        $searchfor[$i] = "|(" . $searchfor[$i] . ").*|Ui";
    }

    $lURL = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    // Bit of a hack, the query string may have multiple ? and & so just knock the url= bit off the querystring
    $lURL = substr($lURL, 4, strlen($lURL));
    $lNewURL = preg_replace($searchfor, $replacewith, $lURL);   
    $lNewURL = str_replace("%TARGET%", $lURL, $lNewURL);;
    $lNewURL = str_replace("%ENCODED_TARGET%", urlencode($lURL), $lNewURL);;

    header("location: $lNewURL"); 
    exit;
}


function st_affiliate_links_options_page()
{
    add_options_page('Automatic Affiliate Links Options', 'Automatic Affiliate Links', 9, 'st_auto_affiliate_links_options.php');
}


if (function_exists('add_action') && function_exists('add_filter')) 
{
    add_action('admin_head', 'st_affiliate_links_options_page');
    add_filter('the_content', 'ConvertURLs', 1);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have a lonnnnnng way young grasshopper. Your first issue to be solved, is you 'insufficient privileges issue'. Secondly you will want to use the wordpress link for your form action which is : `<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>`

Then, you may want to look into session handling for other various issues that you are bound to run into. See here: http://devondev.com/2012/02/03/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/

I would share more links, but I know that Google will lead you to the right place.
I know this to be true, as I was in the same situation 1 week ago.